# Trying to use a CTE calculation to update a column

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to update column3, based on a calculation which is happening between column1 and column2. The theory is relatively simple, however I seem to be struggling with CTE's. If column1 is not null, then column1 * AVG(column2) gets put in column3.

I have searched the forums and tried a few different methods, including CTE and standard UPDATE queries. I seem to be making a mistake.

```
WITH cte_avg1 AS (
    SELECT "column1" * AVG("column2") AS avg
    FROM table1
    )
    UPDATE table1
    SET "column3" = cte_avg1.avg
    FROM cte_avg1
    WHERE "column1" IS NOT NULL;
```

The error message which I am getting is as follows;

> ERROR:  column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 5:     SELECT "column1" * AVG("column2"...

Comment: The CTE is irrelevant - you'd get the same error outside a CTE. The issue is with the query that happens to be in the CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an aggregating query all columns after `SELECT` must either be in the `GROUP BY` clause or a parameter to an aggregation function. Move the multiplication out of the CTE.

```
WITH cte_avg1
AS
(
SELECT avg(column2) avg
       FROM table1
)
UPDATE table1
       SET column3 = column1 * cte_avg1.avg
       FROM cte_avg1
       WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL;
```